# How to boost fields with random sort in solr

Tags: solr

I have multidimensional field 'Topics' in solr. Topics are stored comma separated (eg. Topics:'Art','culture','books'). I want to boost particular value (eg. 'Art') from 'Topics' along with dynamic random sorting.

In short, I want 30% documents for 'Art' within randomly sorted documents. How to achieve this using solr?

Answer (score 1):

you use two things:

1. a [filter query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html), to get only documents with Art topics: &fq=topics:Art
2. a [random sort field](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html) for the sorting: &sort=random_1234 desc